# set related product name in an opportunity field

Tags: apex, opportunity, product

im trying setting an opportunity field with the name of a related product (there is always only one related product to each opportunity).

but , because im a new admin , im yet not fully control apex,

i though on trying OpportunityLineItems object (in an opportunity apex trigger) and form there get the connection

but i couldn't find the right code for using the LineItems on Opportunity controller.

could some one help me with the code, its very important for us.

thnx

oron.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    list<opportunity> lt = trigger.new[0];
list<opportunityLineItem> opli = new list<opportunityLineItem>([select id ,product2.name, opportunityId from opportunitylineitem where opportunityId =: trigger.new[0].id);
string productName='';
for(opportunityLineItem o : opli){
 productName = o.product2.name;
}
for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
 opp.custom_field__c = productName;
 lt.add(opp);
}
update lt;
```

Here, I am updating the custom_field__c in opportunity with a product name in the opportunity line items.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: hi man , thanx alot for the answer ( im both channels (: )

but, im getting an error - Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Opportunity to List<Opportunity> at line 3 column 20
(line 3 is first line in your code)
thanx again

Comment: Use this line instead. This will solve your error.
list<opportunity> lt = trigger.new;
 And please select as answer if it helps.